# functions with if else statement to prompt javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have been racking my brain why this doesn't work, I am sure that I am over thinking it but after googling for a few hours I just can't find it.

So the main thing I am trying is to create a JavaScript function “legs” which takes animal Object and returns some custom message (String) if the animal has 0 legs, 2, 4, and one message for others.

My attempt:

```
var animal = prompt("Type in an animal")

function legs(animal){

    if(animal == 'fish'){
        return "no legs";
    }else if(animal == 'Tiger'){
        return "4 legs";
    }else if(animal == 'kangaroo'){
        return "2 legs";
    }else { 
        return "I don't know";
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're never calling the `legs` function

Comment: You don't call the function.

Comment: ^... leads to even a more fundamental question: Where are you expecting to see the return value of the function?

Comment: Not related, but I can't help myself: kangaroos have 4 legs. Just like we, humans.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I thought humans belong to primates ..?

Comment: @Teemu indeed, and as primates we belong to a bigger monophyletic group called Tetrapoda. All tetrapods have 4 legs as the plesiomorphic condition. Some tetrapods lost legs as an apomorphic condition (eg snakes, whales), but even those have 4 legs in some early stage of development.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Bah, the joke doesn't work in english, in my native language "primate" is "a creature with hands" ...

Comment: I was overthinking it, All I was missing was the alert on the bottom calling the function like you guys said, thank you.

Comment: @Teemu interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `legs` function like `legs(animal)`

```js
var animal = prompt("Type in an animal")

function legs(animal){

    if(animal == 'fish'){
        return "no legs";
    }else if(animal == 'Tiger'){
        return "4 legs";
    }else if(animal == 'kangaroo'){
        return "2 legs";
    }else { 
        return "I don't know";
        }
}
console.log(legs(animal));
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what I did wrong. Thank you for your help. I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

this way you can call the `leg()` function.

```js
var animal = prompt("Type in an animal")

function legs(animal) {
   if (animal == 'fish') 
      return "no legs";
    else if (animal == 'Tiger') 
      return "4 legs";
    else if (animal == 'kangaroo') 
      return "2 legs";
    else 
      return "I don't know";
}

let result = legs(animal)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just improving the answer.
You to get the answer you need to call the function you have defined. Anyway better (cleaner) if you define it before reaching the interactive part (prompt).

Since you are returning in each scenario you do not need to use an else.

```
function legs(animal) {
  if (animal == 'fish') 
    return "no legs";
  if (animal == 'Tiger') 
    return "4 legs";
  if (animal == 'kangaroo') 
    return "2 legs";

  return "I don't know";
}

const animal = prompt("Type in an animal");

console.log(legs(animal));
```